# search for keys from an array list

Tags: javascript

I have array

```
let final = [];
let temp = ['test', 'test 2', 'test 45'];
let data = [{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id: 1, name: "test 2"}, {id: 1, name: "test 100"}, {id: 1, name: "test 45"}]

data.foreach((element) => {
    if(element.name === "test") {
        final.push(element):
    }
});
```

The above works only for one keyword.

Desired output :

```
[{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id: 1, name: "test 2"}, {id: 1, name: "test 45"}]
```

Comment: `if (temp.includes(element.name))` ?

Comment: you can use `filter` like this `const final = data.filter(d => temp.includes(d.name))`